# Executing multiple SQL commands INSERT and SELECT using SQL Reader and Response.Write

Tags: c#, python, asp.net, sql-server, sqldatareader

Response.Write("text"); is rendering on my page load but when I click my button, it does not print.

I am trying to carry out two INSERT commands and one SELECT. I am using the Response.Write to test if the SELECT command is getting the ID I need.

The INSERT commands are working successfully (as the data is been sent to the database) but for some reason I can not access the SprintBacklogID from the Select command. I need the value of the ID to use in a if statement but for the time been, I just need to be able to access the variable in the SELECT statement.

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Response.Write("test");
}

protected void addSprintTasks(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Response.Write("another test");
    string taskDescription = Desc.Text;
    string taskHours = Hours.Text;
    string hoursLeft = Hours.Text;
    string ProductStoryID = Request.QueryString["ProductStoryID"];
    string SprintBacklogID = Request.QueryString["SprintBacklogID"];

    int TaskId;

    string connectionString = WebConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["GiraConnection"].ConnectionString;
    SqlConnection myConnection = new SqlConnection(connectionString);

    myConnection.Open();

    //string query = "INSERT INTO [SprintTasks] (TaskDescription , EstimatedHours, ProductStoryID, RemainingHours, SprintBacklogID) VALUES (@TaskDescription , @EstimatedHours, @ProductStoryID, @RemainingHours, @SprintBacklogID)";
    //string query1 = "INSERT INTO DailyBurndown (TaskID,Date,HoursRemaining) VALUES (@TaskID, @EstimatedHours, @RemainingHours)";

    //create two insert statements under the one connection so the variables can be referenced

    string sql1 = "BEGIN INSERT INTO [SprintTasks] (TaskDescription , EstimatedHours, ProductStoryID, RemainingHours, SprintBacklogID) VALUES (@TaskDescription , @EstimatedHours, @ProductStoryID, @RemainingHours, @SprintBacklogID)SET @ID = SCOPE_IDENTITY();",
           //sqlTest = @"SELECT SprintID FROM SprintTasks WHERE (SprintTasks.SprintBacklogID = @SprintBacklogID);",
           sql2 = "INSERT INTO [DailyBurndown] (TaskID,Date,HoursRemaining) VALUES (@ID, @EstimatedHours, @EstimatedHours); END;";

    string sql = string.Format("{0}{1}", sql1, sql2);


    string query1 = "SELECT SprintBacklogID FROM SprintTasks WHERE (SprintTasks.SprintBacklogID = @SprintBacklogID)";

    //using sql1 and sql2

    using (SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
    {
        using (SqlCommand myCommand = new SqlCommand(sql, connection))
        {

            connection.Open();

            myCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@TaskDescription", taskDescription);
            myCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@EstimatedHours", taskHours);
            myCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@RemainingHours", hoursLeft);
            myCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ProductStoryID", ProductStoryID);
            myCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@SprintBacklogID", SprintBacklogID);

            //Takes the ID for the task just added to the Sprint Sub Tasks table using Scope Identity
            myCommand.Parameters.Add("@ID", SqlDbType.Int, 4).Direction = ParameterDirection.Output;
            myCommand.ExecuteNonQuery();

            //change over sql statement
            myCommand.CommandText = query1;
            myCommand.ExecuteNonQuery();

            using (SqlDataReader reader = myCommand.ExecuteReader())
            {
                while (reader.Read())
                {
                   Response.Write(reader["SprintBacklogID"].ToString());
                }
            }
            Response.Redirect(Request.RawUrl);
            connection.Close();
        }
    }

    myConnection.Open();

}
```

Comment: this is because `Button Clicks` trigger what is called `PostBacks`

Comment: Consider using verbatim string literals to create multi line strings without having to concatenate strings: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/tokens/verbatim

Comment: Why are you using `Response.Write`? You have no control over where that ends up in the markup. Why not append the HTML to an existing control on the page? Why are you properly following the IDisposable pattern (wrapping your IDisposable objects in using statements) in some places but not others?

Comment: when you are trying to execute the Select query, change that to `ExecuteScalar()` `ExecuteNonQuery - is used for Inserts Updates and Deletes`

Comment: When you say "for some reason I can not access the SprintBacklogID from the Select command", do you mean you get back zero records from the `SELECT`? Is there an error? What is the behavior?

Comment: you're actually executing `query1` *twice* - once as a non-query, once via a reader; also - you then redirect, so ... what you write to the response is either going to be discarded (if buffered), or it will fundamentally fail (if not buffered)

Comment: Response.write is just to test with, i wont be using it in my markup when I can see that the ID can be returned through the SELECT command

Comment: @KellyM1996 but you can't test with that if you're doing a redirect...

Comment: I think redirect could be the culprit here.

Comment: Ive changed myCommand to ExecuteScalar() and its still not working. I am not getting any errors or reposonse to whats been returned from the SELECT

Comment: when i remove the redirect i get the following error:
The connection was not closed. The connection's current state is open.

even though the connection is closed?

Comment: Instead of `Response.Write`, why not just assign it to a variable and debug it to make sure you are getting the value back?

Answer (score 1):

You are using `Response.Redirect(Request.RawUrl);`, so assuming the output is being buffered: anything you wrote to the page is discarded, with the redirect taking precedence.

Comment: On taking this redirect out, its complaining that the connection is not closed even though it is? Ive added in two connection open/closes either side of the executes but still no luck

Comment: @KellyM1996 You shouldn't need to manually close your connections. The using statement will take care of that. Make sure you are actually using the using statements though, because you did it for one of your connections but not the other. You'll still have to manually open it though.